# Drag and Drop in a GWT FlexTable

Tags: java, gwt, dynamic, drag-and-drop, flextable

I'm working on a drag'n'drop functionality in a GWT project and I need to do widgets drag'n'droping onto a `FlexTable`.

I saw some examples on DnD within `AbsolutePanel`... etc, and I did researches on it, but I didn't find any information on the above mentioned problem.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in GWT. Perhaps it's easier with some GWT extension such as [Smart GWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/). See this [example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_interaction_drag_copy). Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I know about Smart GWT, it overloads the browser with big amounts of MB. and it's very slow.

Comment: It has no flextable maturity as well!

Comment: You could try GXT there are currently moving to be in line with the latest GWT and have used UI binder and code splitting as much as possible.

Comment: GXT is full of bugs (more buggy than GWT), and they don't have FlexTable and its capabilities. We're using FlexTable extensively in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a matter of fact I finished coding, and it works super. It took me one whole week! But not with `GWTQuery`, I used only `GWT`.

1. I moved the `FlexTable` into a `AbsolutePanel` to manipulate the
   dragged objects from the `FlexTable` cells
2. I used java events, mouse events and handlers
3. I used `FocusPanel` to map the events to
4. Manipulated the FlexTable in a lot of sections of event handling in
   dragging and dropping objects

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider the drag and drop plugin of gwtquery ?

It offers the possibility to make any widget (the new cell widgets included) draggable and/or droppable easily and it is fully configurable.

Take a look a the doc : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

and at the examples : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/GwtSimpleSample/GwtSimpleSample.html

Comment: The suggested gwtquery is a whole new platfrom other than the main GWT platform which we are working on, and to change from plalform to another, will give a lot of pan in the B.

Comment: Not at all, gwtquery is complementary to gwt. I'm using it in my gwt project within my views for easing DOM manipulation. Do you read the documentation ? The plugin offers a GWT like api with widget et cie

Comment: OK, since you're using gwtquery in your project and you've got experience using it, I will ask you if there is any built in 'drag and drop' mechanism that applies on the widgets of flexTable to drag and drop in that table?

Comment: FYI I'm trying to write a GwtQuery + FlexTable drag and drop right now. Not super simple, since I'm new to GwtQuery too, but I'm using the http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/GwtPortletSample/GwtPortletSample.html as a starting point.

Comment: In a matter of fact I finished coding, and it works super. It took me one whole week! But not with GWTQuery, I used only GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Working with `DnD` in `AbsolutePanel` is a thing and working with `FlexTable` is another:
It is very difficult to maintain `DnD` in `FlexTable` since it has a lot of manipulation things to be done concerning rows and columns, on adding *positioners*, removing and adding widgets, is a lot of pain in the A**. but worth trying it.